# Customer confirmation field in magento database

Tags: mysql, magento

My website got some problem with confirmation mail. So a lot of customer cannot confirm their account. I can confirm thier account in backend but i want to do it with mysql query to save time. I look for confirmation field in database but no sign of it. Anyone knows where it is?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did some RND and find out this. if you would like to do it inside Magento, you can load a customer through id then

```
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->save();
```

`'confirmation'` is in `eav_attribute` table, joined with `customer_eav_attribute`

Comment: it seem not true 'cause all row in my table have value '1', but in backend, alot of account is still not confirm